# According to which rule, the maritime patrol aircraft are categorized?

Tags: military, search-and-rescue, surveillance, rules-of-the-air, marine-one

Generally, maritime patrol missions are conducted by several types of fixed wing and rotor wing aircraft according to its endurance, capabilities and other features such as weapons, sensors surveillance payload onboard aircraft. Each aircraft is selected for a mission considering above facts. I want to know that, is there an international rule or guideline to follow when selecting the particular aircraft?

Comment: What sort of rule, and why might there be an international rule?  (You highlighted some good criteria)

Comment: It would not make any sense to have an “International” rule or guideline. Each country’s requirements would be different  to satisfy their own needs.

Comment: There is no such rule. A country uses what resources it has, to meet the desired mission. It makes no sense for Mexico or South Africa to consider "rules" for a MQ-4C Triton, because they do not have any.

Answer (score 2):

As a military aircraft, they are regulated under FAA Chapter "get outta here, civilian, or I'll call Shore Patrol and have you arrested for trespassing".

In other words, it's military, so *anything goes*.

If an aircraft can fly and is fit for mission, or even if it's not, by golly it can be in the air. Indeed, the lowly Antonov-2 cropduster has been used for the most absurd things - insurgency operations, COIN operations, tactical airlifter, and Russia has gathered about fifty they're planning to use as drones to try to saturate Ukraine air defense.   Come to it, it would make a first-rate maritime patrol aircraft, being able to carry the huge Mk. 48 anti-large-ship torpedo, and about six of the small Mk. 50 ASW torps....

... except for the problem that most submarines could outrun the Antonov-2 :)

Comment: I think the slightly more formal name for the chapter you're referring to is "due regard."  Which isn't strictly an FAA thing, but part of international conventions.